# vim syntax match regex not working as expected

Tags: regex, vim

I'm experimenting with Vim's syntax conceal option, with the hopes of contributing back to [vim-lambdify](https://github.com/calebsmith/vim-lambdify). However, I'm seeing (to my mind) unexpected behavior when trying to pass a regex to `syntax match`.

When specifying the following in my .vimrc

```
execute "syntax match myOperator /foo\(bar\)\@=/ conceal cchar=*"
execute "hi link myOperator mySpecialOperator"
execute "hi! link Conceal mySpecialOperator"
setlocal conceallevel=1
setlocal concealcursor=c
```

I don't see `foo` concealed when opening the following file:

```
foo
foob
foobar
```

I've tried many permutations of this regex: escaping nothing/everything, wrapping it with single/double quotes, etc. to no avail.

Am I missing something obvious? Am I misunderstanding how syntax/match/conceal are supposed to work together?

Comment: Why are you using exec? Removing exec would still make the command work...

Comment: In the first line, the use of execute with double quotes is wrong because the backslashes are interpreted, you should use single quotes, or put some double backslashes, or remove `execute`

Comment: Unfortunately, [the plugin](https://github.com/calebsmith/vim-lambdify/blob/master/autoload/vimlambdify.vim#L27) I'm interested in extending uses `execute "syntax match ..."`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question was answered on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/3p8ucz/trouble_with_syntax_match_regex/) by [rgvim](https://www.reddit.com/user/rgvim):

> The backslashes in the first execute string need to be escaped.

```
/foo\\(bar\\)\\@=/
```